# Extract text where a part of text inside <br> tag using only Xpath

Tags: python, xpath

I want to grab only string from here :

```
                  <br>

                5 Brown Circle<br>

                Alabaster,

                AL &nbsp;&nbsp;

                35007
```

I need solid understanding how to extract text from the above portion following html doc:

```
<tr class="prem-tr" id="10425" role="row">
                    <td>
                        <h4><a class="prem-result-link" href="/Search/Details/10425">Graham &amp; Associates, CPAs</a></h4>

                        <a href="tel:+(205) 663-6673">(205) 663-6673</a>
                        <br>

                        5 Brown Circle<br>

                        Alabaster,

                        AL &nbsp;&nbsp;

                        35007

                        <div class="row result-btmRow">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <span class="result-dist"><small>Distance: 0.00 miles</small></span>
                            </div><!-- col6 -->
                            <div class="col-sm-8 result-actions">
                                <a id="WebsiteURL" class="visit-site" href="http://grahamandassociates.net" target="_blank">Visit Website</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;

                                <a class="send-email" href="/Search/Details/10425">Send a Message</a>
                            </div><!-- /col6 -->
                        </div><!-- /row -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Expected output:`5 Brown Circle, Alabaster, AL 35007` using only xpath along with explanation.

OR

In css selectors, it's working  fine.Can anyone explain the following code? Thanks

```
" ".join([" ".join(el.root.strip().split()) for el in sel.css("td::text") if el.root.strip()])
```

Comment: Show how you tried

Comment: Take a look at elementTree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not say this is a great solution, but if the requirement is to use only XPath 1.0...

`normalize-space(translate(concat(//td/text()[4], //td/text()[5]),"\xa0", ""))`

Breaking it down a bit and demonstrating in iPython with `lxml.etree`:

All of the text nodes that are children of the `td` can be selected with `//td/text()`. This excludes the name and phone number because they are descendants but not children.

```
In [73]: root.xpath('//td/text()')
Out[73]: 
['\n                        ',
 '\n\n                        ',
 '\n                        ',
 '\n\n                        5 Brown Circle',
 '\n\n                        Alabaster,\n\n                        AL \xa0\xa0\n\n                        35007\n\n                        ',
 '\n                    ']
```

Ideally we could join all these strings and normalize the whitespace with `normalize-space()`, but this is awkward because in XPath 1.0, we have only `concat()` available to us, which only takes two arguments. Handling this in Python with `join()` would be better, but because there are only two text nodes that we're interested in, we can use `concat()` to concatenate the fourth and fifth text nodes in the set for a pure XPath solution.

```
In [74]: root.xpath('concat(//td/text()[4], //td/text()[5])')
Out[74]: '\n\n                        5 Brown Circle\n\n                        Alabaster,\n\n                        AL \xa0\xa0\n\n                        35007\n\n                        '
```

Now we can apply `normalize-space()` to clean up the whitespace.

```
In [75]: root.xpath('normalize-space(concat(//td/text()[4], //td/text()[5]))')
Out[75]: '5 Brown Circle Alabaster, AL \xa0\xa0 35007'              '
```

Almost there. Now we just have to get rid of the non-breaking space characters with `translate()` before we normalize the space.

```
In [79]: root.xpath('normalize-space(translate(concat(//td/text()[4], //td/text()[5]),"\xa0", ""))')
Out[79]: '5 Brown Circle Alabaster, AL 35007'
```

Note that because this is Python, we must use `\xa0` instead of `&nbsp;` or `&#160;` to represent the non-breaking space character.

Comment: Why do we use translate  method here? Will you explain a bit?

Comment: Certainly. `translate()` searches for instances of single characters in a string and replaces them with other single characters. If no character is specified, the original character is just removed instead. So here, `translate()` is being used to erase the non-breaking space characters (`&nbsp;` in the original) so that the whitespace in the result matches your requirement. (`normalize-space()` handles most whitespace, but not non-breaking space characters.)

Comment: Well, You've concatenated  text . Will you elaborate a bit of which portion indicate that text from the html doc?

Comment: Thanks. It's working fine but I'm not understanding only the concatenation 4 and 5 . Will you show me how have you done that?

Comment: name and phone number are grand children not direct child. Great! explanation. This time. I've understood everything. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Handling of the `&nbsp` entity and the unclosed `<br>` tags may differ depending on exactly which XPath processor you are using, but the following will produce the exact result requested:

```
//td/text()[string-length(normalize-space(.)) > 0]/normalize-space(translate(.,'&#160;',''))
```

Where

- `//td` selects all of the td nodes (just one in the example),
- /`text()` selects all of the text nodes that are immediate children of the `td`,
- predicate `[string-length(normalize-space(.)) > 0]` eliminates any text nodes that, when stripped of leading/trailing whitespace, are zero-length strings,
- `/normalize-space(translate(.,'&#160;',''))` replaces the `nbsp` characters with nothing and eliminates leading/trailing whitespace from the remaining text nodes.

Comment: Great! but have a little bit question:  What's the meaning (.) here and why do we use &#160 to remove  &nbsp  as replacement.

Comment: The `&nbsp` entities are actual characters and you did not show them in your intended output.   '&#160'  is just the numeric reference (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274315/is-160-a-replacement-of-nbsp) .  In XPath, the dot refers to the context item.  For example, in the expression `text()[string-length(normalize-space(.)) > 0]` the dot refers to the text() node the predicate is applied to.

Comment: Not working how? What errors or unintended output are you receiving?

Comment: I was experimenting with my answer more and noticed it is actually returning two text nodes instead of one.  If your XPath processor supports a version of XPath having the string-join() function, it may be possible to return this as one string, but your exact whitespace requirements may be challenging to achieve.